# Assign onclick Events to radiobutton Using the HTML DOM

Tags: jquery, onclick, radio-button, onload

```
<input type="radio" name="sam1" value="1">HI
<input type="radio" name="sam1" value="2">HI HI
```

Actually i am try to add on click event to the above mention radio button

```
$("input:radio[name=sam1]").onclick = function () {disp()};
```

Please correct my code

```
function disp(){//content here}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

it is

```
//dom ready handler
jQuery(function ($) {
    $("input:radio[name=sam1]").click(disp)
})
```

The `onlick` property is used when you are trying to add a event handler to a dom element reference, here `$("input:radio[name=sam1]")` is a jQuery wrapper so you can use the event utilities provided by jQuery to register the event handler like [.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/tXUYZ/)

Answer (score 6):

Hope this link might help you.. :)

```
$("input:radio[name=sam1]").click(function(){
 disp();
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/nibin_10/JNyAB/

Answer (score 4):

You are mixing jquery and javascript here.

Use like this  :

```
function disp(){
    //content here
}
$("input:radio[name=sam1]").click(disp)
```

Here is the demo :http://jsfiddle.net/Nz4ET/

Answer (score 2):

```
Try this
<input type="radio" name="sam1" value="1">HI

<input type="radio" name="sam1" value="2">HI HI

<script>
$('input:radio[name=sam1]').click(function(){
    disp()
});
function disp()
{
    alert('Hello'); 
}
  </script>
```

Comment: i need to add click event to radio button using jquery